# zerorpc in flask app is not working when launched in apache server but working fine when launched by pycharm

Tags: python, apache, python-2.7, flask, zeromq

I am using flask application to display the data read using zero rpc subscriber.
While developing it was working fine as I was launching the app using Pycharm But once deployed in Apache server the subscriber is not able to fetch any data. Basically the method in subscriber is not getting called even though the publisher is publishing the data.

Thanks

Edit: (adding more info):

In app_start.py

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import stratgy_subscriber
startegy_state_info_provider = stratgy_subscriber.StartegyStateInfoProvider()
@app.route('/')
def strategy_info():
    return startegy_state_info_provider.ip_port_to_subscriber_map[('0.0.0.0', '4249')]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startegy_state_info_provider.start_subscriber('0.0.0.0', '4249')
    app.run()
```

I am connecting to subscriber using following code. 
In stratgy_subscriber.py

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()

class StartegyStateInfoProvider(object):

  def __init__(self):  
      self.ip_port_to_subscriber_map = {}

  def start_subscriber(machine_ip, port):
      strategy_state_subscriber = StrategyStateSubscriber()
      ip_port_to_subscriber_map[(machine_ip, port)] = strategy_state_subscriber
      end_point = 'tcp://' + machine_ip + ':' + port
      strategy_state_subscriber = zerorpc.Subscriber(strategy_state_subscriber)
      strategy_state_subscriber.connect(end_point)
      gevent.spawn(strategy_state_subscriber.run)

class StrategyStateSubscriber():
  def __init__(self):
    self.strategy_id_to_info_map = {}
  def update_strategy_state(self, strategy_id, updated_strategy_state): 
    from datetime import datetime
    current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S')
    updated_strategy_state.append(current_time)
    print updated_strategy_state
    strategy_id_to_info_map[strategy_id] = updated_strategy_state
```

This is the Publisher`

```
endpoint = "tcp://0.0.0.0:4249"
publisher = zerorpc.Publisher()
publisher.bind(endpoint)

for a in xrange(0, 1000):
    info = [False, a * a, 3 * a, a % 20, a % 50]
    publisher.update_strategy_state(a, info)
    if a < 50:
        gevent.sleep(1)
    elif a >= 50:
        gevent.sleep(2)
```

After subscription i.e. gevent.spawn(strategy_state_subscriber.run), update_strategy_state should get called each time the publisher publishes the data which is not happening.

I am getting following exception:

```
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]   File "/home/sricharan/git_ceres_viewer/src/strategy_state_subscription.py", line 68, in subscribe
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]     subscriber = zerorpc.Subscriber(service)
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/core.py", line 371, in __init__
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]     zmq_socket=zmq.SUB)
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/core.py", line 312, in __init__
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]     super(Puller, self).__init__(zmq_socket, context=context)
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/socket.py", line 34, in __init__
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]     self._events = Events(zmq_socket_type, context)
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/events.py", line 177, in __init__
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]     self._socket = zmq.Socket(self._context, zmq_socket_type)
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/zerorpc/gevent_zmq.py", line 61, in __init__
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]     self.__dict__["_state_event"] = gevent.hub.get_hub().loop.io(
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 135, in get_hub
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error]     raise NotImplementedError('gevent is only usable from a single thread')
[Wed May 28 11:24:03 2014] [error] NotImplementedError: gevent is only usable from a single thread
```

After some research I found out that :- 
gevent isn't compatible with Apache's multithreaded worker model

Comment: Your system consist of couple of components and you will have to investigate one by one, if all works as expected. This is not possible to do from the description you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jan.
But my concern is why its happening only in apache server not when using Pycharm IDE?
And which component is affected when deployed in apache server.
Struggling for the solution for couple of days.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky
I am connecting to subscriber using following code.
`
strategy_state_subscriber = StrategyStateSubscriber()
end_point = 'tcp://' + machine_ip + ':' + port
strategy_state_subscriber = zerorpc.Subscriber(strategy_state_subscriber)
strategy_state_subscriber.connect(end_point)
gevent.spawn(strategy_state_subscriber.run)
`

Comment: @JanVlcinsky 

This is the StrategyStateSubscriber class.

`
class StrategyStateSubscriber():

    def update_strategy_state(self, strategy_id, updated_strategy_state):
        from datetime import datetime
 current_time = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%H:%M:%S')
 updated_strategy_state.append(current_time)
 self.__strategy_id_to_state_map[strategy_id] = updated_strategy_state

`

Comment: It is better to put additional info for the question into the question - easier to read (I did it for you). Add more info yourself, it is hard to read in comments. Anyway, I still have no idea, what is going on. Either add more info (do not focus on what you think is wrong, but on what allow others to reproduce the problem). Or better - split your problem to pieces and test one by one.

Comment: I am not sure you have enough credit to edit your post so I did it again. Not sure, I formatted it properly.

Comment: @JanVlcinsky Thanks for the tips 

I have added some more info to reproduce the error

Comment: Please, add all required imports into your question. I found `zerorpc` very promising and would like to test it, but in some places I miss something, e.g. at "Publisher" I have no idea, where the `.update_strategy_state` comes as method of `publisher` being instance of `zerorpc.Publisher()`.

Comment: I managed the publishing code to publish (those calls of `publisher.update_strategy_state`).

Comment: @JanVlcinsky
    update_strategy_state is a user defined function, on which publisher publishes the data at an end_point (ip, port).
update_strategy_state method of the subscriber will be invoked if subscriber is subscribing to this end point

Comment: I managed consuming published calls, but had to add one line after `gevent.spawn(strategy_state_subscriber.run)` which actually gave the code a chance to run. I added `gevent.sleep(5)` and immediately got the data printed. Without that, the code of the subscriber simply runs out without any chance to receive any call from publisher. There could be other calls of this kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

```
import zerorpc
import gevent
from subscrclass import StrategyStateSubscriber
strategy_state_subscriber = StrategyStateSubscriber()
machine_ip = "127.0.0.1"
port = "5555"
end_point = "tcp://" + machine_ip + ":" + port

strategy_state_subscriber = zerorpc.Subscriber(strategy_state_subscriber)

strategy_state_subscriber.connect(end_point)
gevent.spawn(strategy_state_subscriber.run)
gevent.sleep(5) # This line was added
```

Original code with subsriber call ended with spawning it, but did not actually give any chance for the code to do anything.

If I added `gevent.sleep(5)`, coroutines got a chance to run for 5 seconds and the prints were appearing.

Be sure to use some `gevent` call, simple `time.sleep(5)` does not work as it is blocking one and coroutines have no chance to say a word or run a line of code.

With your PyCharm IDE I can imagine, you either had similar line present, or you were performing the actions "slowly", and it had a chance to run. But this is pure speculation - important is to give in your code a chance to your coroutines to run before your code exits.

## Complete example (without Flask part)

Here is complete runnable sample

### `subscrclass.py`

This class will actually receive calls from publisher. It is important:

- having name `update_strategy_state`
- having 2 parameters

Here it goes:

```
from datetime import datetime

class StrategyStateSubscriber():
    def update_strategy_state(self, strategy_id, state):
        print datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%H:%M:%S"), state
```

### `pub.py`

Here is the publisher.

It does not import anything to get the StrategyStateSubscriber, it only creates a call to some remote subscriber, which might have implemented a method named `update_strategy_state` with two parameters.

```
import gevent
import zerorpc

publisher = zerorpc.Publisher()
publisher.bind("tcp://0.0.0.0:5555")

for a in xrange(0, 1000):
    publisher.update_strategy_state(a, [False, a * a, 3 * a, a % 20, a % 50])
    gevent.sleep(1 if a < 50 else 2)
```

### `client.py`

Finally we come to client, who subscribes to published calls and passes them to relevant method (decided by publisher) implemented on class `StrategySateSubscriber`

```
import zerorpc
import gevent
from subscrclass import StrategyStateSubscriber

strategy_state_subscriber = zerorpc.Subscriber(StrategyStateSubscriber())
strategy_state_subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555")
gevent.spawn(strategy_state_subscriber.run)
gevent.sleep(5)
```

It is important to allow spawned process to run, here we call `gevent.sleep(5)`, other calls or non-blocking I/0 operations could help too.

### Running the code

In first console start the publisher:

```
$ python pub.py
```

In second console, start the client:

```
$ python client.py 
22:30:06 [False, 16, 12, 4, 4]
22:30:07 [False, 25, 15, 5, 5]
22:30:08 [False, 36, 18, 6, 6]
22:30:09 [False, 49, 21, 7, 7]
22:30:10 [False, 64, 24, 8, 8]
```

## Conclusions

- zerorpc turns to be really powerful tool
- with spawning processes, programmers sometime forget to give the code a chance to run. This was the cause here.
- In case, the web page in Flask shall return quickly, it would be faster using request/response (remote procedure call) instead of sleeping to get some data.
- In case, the strategy status is to be fed to client in long term (e.g. by WebSockets), publish/subscribe messaging patterns is best fitting one.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I try to implement this and let you know whether it worked or not. 
But I think gevent.spawn() will run forever and I used ` from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all() `. My flask app also runs for long time enough to capture the published data.
 P.S. the same code without any sleep runs fine when launched by Pycharm

Comment: @SricharanMadasi Without some waiting instruction it will be like pouring water into basin with open sink. `spawn` starts new thread, but does not wait - it is actually the purpose of it - start new thread and go on having free hands. And in your Flask app, your code generating some output exits as soon as you have your request processing finished. This request processing is mostly very quick (and you want have your response generated quickly), so the request processing code does not run for very long.

Comment: @SricharanMadasi Btw, where did you learn using `zerorpc` this way? I did not find any tutorial and documentation is rather short on this. I like this and would like to learn something more.

Comment: Actually the code gevent.spawn() is called on start of the application and will run foreever. 
updated_strategy_state for each strategy_id is stored in server side in a dict.
On request from web I fetch the data stored in server and display on browser.
Main problem is update_strategy_state function it self is not called. ( I have added logs and checked)

Comment: Below is th link for som examples of pub/sub and push/pull....https://github.com/dotcloud/zerorpc-python/blob/master/tests/test_pubpush.py

Comment: @SricharanMadasi Could you share the Flask code? (and thanks for link to the test suite).

Comment: I have added the flask code in the question.

Comment: @SricharanMadasi The code you have provided is incomplete and cannot be run. It does not even show, how you share updated status with your request and this probably hides root of the problem. Also imports are missing. If you attempt to create minimal working example, you either find the problem, or help me or others to answer.

Comment: As I don't have the code in this system, I will update the actual code in few hours once I log in to office machine.
Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question with the code similar to my flask app.
I will update the exact code tomorrow. Apology for the delay.

Comment: gevent isn't compatible with Apache's multithreaded worker model

Comment: @SricharanMadasi That is sad. But one becomes expert by failing in all possible ways. Did you try `nginx`? I am not sure, it supports gevent, but it might.